# some threads do not participate in running the code

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a parallel fortran code with OpenMP. This is the parallel part of code:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(iconf,d,randx,                   &
!$OMP& randy,randz,unit_cg,theta1,theta2,theta3,fr1,fr2,fr3,Q,          &
!$OMP& plproduct_avg,correlation_term) 

      allocate(randx(num),randy(num),randz(num),unit_cg(num),           &
     &         fr1(num),fr2(num),fr3(num),theta1(order,num),            &
     &         theta2(order,num),theta3(order,num),                     &
     &         Q(nfftdim1,nfftdim2,nfftdim3))

!$OMP DO 
      do 250 iconf = 1,1600
       write(6,*)'configuration number',iconf

       {some calculations}

       write(6,*)'correlation term of iconf =',iconf,                   &
 &            correlation_term(iconf)

250   continue
!$OMP END DO

      deallocate(randx,randy,randz,unit_cg,fr1,fr2,fr3,theta1,theta2,   &
     &           theta3,Q)

!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

When I run this code on 40 threads ( I set the number of thread on script 40 ), the program enters 40 loops, and in output file I have 40 lines like this:

```
configuration number         161
```

with different numbers. So I figure out that all 40 threads start to work. Therefore This line of code

```
       write(6,*)'correlation term of iconf =',iconf,                   &
&            correlation_term(iconf)
```

should be executed 40 times and I should have 40 `correlation_term(iconf)` in output file, but only 37 `correlation_term(iconf)` are in output file, so I conclude that 3 threads do not participate in running the code.

At the next step the program enters only 37 loops and only 35 loops have data. It seems some threads do not participate in running and now only 22 threads do calculations.

Why do not these threads participate? Do I have a mistake in paralleling?

Comment: Yes, and my code is running now, and now I have 22 lines like  `correlation term of iconf = ...`

Comment: Your conclusions may not be correct. Try to make a fully self-contained simple example for verification. Write also the thread number (`omp_get_thread_num()`) and show your real output file.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. until now, I have 236 loops and only 221 `correlation_term(iconf)`. I can not understand what's happened to these 15.

Comment: Hi Mark, my code will last two weeks so I ran my code with small input and wrote `omp_get_thread_num()` as Vladimir suggested . I set number of thread 16. when I put the upper bound of loop 16 (instead of 1600), everything is ok. But when I put the upper bound of loop 40 (more than number of thread), 37 loops do calculations and terminate (in reasonable time) but 3 loops remain without data and the code can not exit the parallel region and stop.

Comment: actually the code can not finish.

Comment: Yes, for 40 loops, for `iconf = 17,24,35` the code can not finish the loop.

Comment: So that's the problem.  The code for those values of `iconf` doesn't finish the loop; `{some calculations}` either stalls or runs on 'forever'.  As the computation progresses other values of `iconf` are encountered which also stall or run forever. *Do I have a mistake in paralleling?*  It seems more likely that the mistake is inside code you haven't shown us, or in your understanding of it.